# QtreeWidget Border Issue

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a qtreewidget in my application. I have set the stylesheet like below for it.

```
setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
setStyleSheet("QTreeView { border: none; background: transparent; outline:none; }" "QTreeView::item:!selected:hover { border: 1px solid #AAAAAA}" "QTreeView::item:selected { border: 1px solid #0053A6}");
```

Now the problem is that there is no border around qtreewidget which is correct behaviour but when I click on any item of this widget a black border appears around the widget. Although I have mentioned the border for this widget to none then why it is appearing on clicking any item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a focus rectangle. To completely disable it:

```
setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)
```